# iScroll, how do I call my scroller?

Tags: javascript, iscroll

The iScroll documentation shows a typical iScroll setup like the one below.

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
    }, 100);
}
window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
```

My question is how do I call the scroller? If I use:

```
var currentItem = 5;
myScroll.scrollToElement('.nav > li:nth-child('+currentItem+')', 300);
```

I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scrollToElement' of undefined
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What did you have to change for this to work ? I think in my case it's not the timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to use the variable name you assigned the iScroll to:

```
myScroll.scrollToElement ...
```

and not

```
scroller.scrollTo ...
```

**Update:**

According to your latter tests, it obviously was a timing error. You proably called `myScroll.scrollToElement` before the timeout function was executed.

Comment: And what does the console yield for `myScroll`?

Comment: Nothing, I've removed the loaded and timeout for now and just instantiated the iScroll in the global scope for now and it's working.

Comment: Then it obviously was a timing error. You proably called `myScroll.scrollToElement` before the timeout function was executed.

Comment: Doh!, probably correct. I think I'll leave it out of the timer for now since it's working, but that was an epic oversight. I'll give you the correct answer for the comment.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer, so it reflects the correct answer. Others may find it useful.

Comment: @acme hello. I'm having the same problem, but I think I dont have any problem with the timeout

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding extra quotation marks within the first parameter.

Remove the quotation marks, and try changing your code to the following

```
myScroll.scrollToElement('.nav > li:nth-child(5)', 300);
```

If you are looking to make the query dynamic, replace the number with a variable and adding plus signs to concatenate the string.

```
var incNumber = 5;
myScroll.scrollToElement('.nav > li:nth-child('+ incNumber +')', 300);
```

It also appears that your iScroll is created with a timeout delay. Is your function being called before the library is instantiated?

Comment: That's a mistake in my efforts to simplify, the real code is similar to yours. scroller.scrollToElement('.nav > li:nth-child('+currentItem+')', 300);

Comment: Do you continue to get the same error? Have you used a javascript console to call `$('.nav > li:nth-child(5)').html()` to double-check whether it exists?

Comment: It doesn't exist. I don't know how to access it. If you initialize the iScroll outside of the loaded function everything works fine, but iScroll documentation says you should initialize it this way. I may just pull it out of this code all together since it works, but I'm just curious as to why I can't access myScroll.

Comment: Could you post the loaded function you are using to verify all of the page elements are completed?